# MySQL query: How to get body concatenation from test1 with space as joint, to get "something1 something2"?

Tags: sql, mysql

setup:

```
mysql> create table main(id integer unsigned);

mysql> create table test1(id integer unsigned,body text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.84 sec)

mysql> insert into main(id) value(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into test1(id,body) value(1,'something1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.27 sec)

mysql> insert into test1(id,body) value(1,'something2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Using

```
mysql> select main.id,body from main
    -> left join test1 on main.id=test1.id
    -> group by main.id;
```

returns:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | body       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | something1 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

How to get body concatenation from test1 with space as joint, to get "something1 something2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT main.id, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN test1 on main.id=test1.id
GROUP BY main.id
```

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for details.